# How to show an url at the bottom corner of a desktop browser window on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter2.0

I am designing a web application using flutter and I want users to be able to see the destination url which usually appear at the bottom corner of desktop browser windows when they click or hover over the elements containing the link on the web page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install plugin https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
Link(uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com', 
     builder: (context, onLlink) {
         return TextButton(child: Text('Click Here'), onPressed: onLlink)
     })
```

For more detailed please check below link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujlqRTJg48g

Comment: 1+ , thats whats am looking for! , but it will be better if you add more details